# C++ Calling a function from main within an implementation file

Tags: c++, function, class

Say that I have a function within my "Main.cpp" file that I need to run within an implementation .cpp file that is within a class. How would I go about this?

Say I have Main.cpp that has function findDate and it needs to be called within a function that is in my class called Dates. The problem with including the Main.cpp file is that everything is getting re-initialized and I cannot seem to get the #ifndef to work within a Main.cpp file. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you move that function to Dates? This seems like the best idea for such a situation...

Comment: Because it is within my error handling within Main that is done before the class object is ever introduced within Main.

Comment: Learn to divide in components, provide headers and implementation files. This is one of the basic tools that will help you manage your code. The function could very well be declared in a different header, and implemented in a different translation unit (cpp), or in the same files that your `Dates` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general procedure for doing this.

#### Create a file called Main.h:

```
#pragma once // Include guard, so you don't include multiple times.

// Declaration (it is okay to have multiple declarations, if they
//              have a corresponding definition somewhere)
date findDate (void);
```

#### Main.cpp:

```
// Definition (it is not okay to have multiple non-static definitions)
date
findDate (void)
{
  // Do some stuff
  return something;
}
```

#### Dates.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

date
Dates::SomeFunction (void)
{
  return ::findDate ();
}
```

Never include "Main.cpp", this will create multiple implementations and symbols of your `findDate (...)` function (assuming the function is not declared `static`), and the linker will be unable to figure out which output object to link to. This is known as a *symbol collision* or *multiple definition* error.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare (but not define) findDate in a file main.h. Then include the .h file at the top of the file where findDate needs to be called.

Comment: How would I go about this? Example?